# Does hashing a cryptographic strong string's bytes weaken its strength

Tags: hash, cryptography

I am not sure exactly if this way will not retain the strength of cryptographic random binary string.

I have generated a random binary string say for example it is 48 bytes and then I hash it using sha384 algorithm, does this weaken the cryptographic strength?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense as is. I'm not even sure what you mean by a random binary string. And neither what you use it for, or why you want to apply a hash function.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you loose strength, as SHA-384 isn't perfect - it should be, but nothing is. As said, without the use case it is difficult to predict how much a difference this makes. You should not loose much though.

Generally, I would consider this a pretty safe operation to perform. Many key derivation schemes use something similar to H(master key material | counter) and then cut off the unnecessary bytes at the end.

But, as CodeInChaos commented, it all depends on the use case.

Comment: Note that newer key derivation schemes use a MAC instead of a hash. This can be a HMAC, and for most of the SHA-3 candidates, directly using the hash should not pose a problem. Earlier hashes miss some cryptographic properties compared with MAC's that make them less usable for KDFs (although I don't know any practical attacks).

Answer (score 1):

SHA-384 is essentially SHA-512+truncation. Since your input is just 384 bits long, hashing it with SHA-512 will give a result that has at most 384 bits of entropy. When now doing the truncation stage SHA-512->SHA-384, you (resp. the message digest function) may end up stripping up to 128 bits of entropy. So there is the possibility in this case to weaken it by an extra hashing step.

Comment: I believe your statement is extremely unlikely to be true. Many security primitives and algorithms make the assumption that the entropy after hashing with a secure hash function is uniformly distributed over the output bits.

Comment: Well, even then. If the 384 bits are equally distributed over the 512 bit MD, there would be 3 entropy bits for every block of 4 output bits (or simply 0.75 b/b). Removing e.g. the trailing 128 bits to go from 512->384 would then remove 128*.75=96 bits. But looking at the worst case should be done too :)

Comment: @jørgensen It doesn't work that way. If it did, a hypothetical 1024 bit hash truncated to 384 bits would contain less entropy from the original string than a 384 bit hash un-truncated. That's not the case for an ideal secure hash function, though.